# Query objects - which layer?

Tags: design-patterns, orm, clean-architecture

I was reading this article [1] about getting rid of repositories and embracing the ORM directly (EF specifically) through the use of Query objects.

Which layer of the Onion architecture/Clean architecture would the Query objects then belong to? I somehow feel they belong to the domain core, but would like to double check.

[1] https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/

Answer (score 1):

In `Clean Architecture` and `Onion Architecture` approach there is no way to use `Query objects` as objects are part of business rules/domain and ORMs/Repositories are part of infrastructure/external interfaces.

Take a look at [Onion Architecture](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) description and [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) description. Both approaches clearly state: *business objects are independent from external sources*. Allowing business object to know how to save/retrieve itself from a database is straight violation of mentioned statement.

By the way, article in your link says

> I don’t think creating an abstraction over your ORM provides much value, nor do I think it is necessarily bad if you use your ORM directly in the UI tier.

Utilizing ORM directly in UI layer is a very bad decision, better never do anything like that and separate layers of responsibility clearly. I suggest you not follow information in that article.

Comment: Author's argument is EF itself implements repository and unit of work patterns, so he claims abstracting behind repository is unnecessary. So instead of creating an `IRepository<T>` and giving it predicates and specifications, we can just treat the `DbContext` as the repository and program against it directly (inject it, save against it, query from it).

Comment: Then, instead of having multiple queries all over, we can put them in a class and name them, thus following SOLID to its logical conclusion.

Comment: Injecting `DbContext` directly into the controller is dubious, I agree.

Comment: @Robotron using bare `DbContext` or hiding it under `IRepository<T>` is a different question. OP asks in the context of `Clean Architecture` or `Onion Architecture`. Ordinary 3-layer architecture allows debates on what you've mentioned, “clean” and “onion” do not. Because referencing anything from EF directly in business layer object will create a dependency.

Comment: If we follow the logic of the article and allow for `DbContext` to represent the repository, then it can get injected into the core. Unless you have a business requirement to switch out ORMs, then you have to hide it behind an interface.

Comment: @Robotron sounds right! Alas, according to the link on “onion architecture” I mentioned in my answer, bare `DbContext` doesn't really decouple `core` from database, only interfaces do. Paragraph **The database is not the center.  It is external** says that. And link about `clean architecture` says:_Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle_. And `DbContext` is totally from an “outer” circle. Overall it's ok to have `DbContext` instead of `IRepo<T>`, the thing is that you won't be able to follow other rules of `Clean Architecture` that way.

Comment: @Robotron okay, maybe I misunderstood you a little bit. I was thinking about `ActiveRecord` pattern as a replacement for `IRepository<T>` all the time. And example in OP's link shows something different, creating another entity which isn't a repository, but which falls under `use case` category in terms of `clean architecture`. And in `onion architecture` it can fall under `domain service`. But what's the difference from `repository` pattern then?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are abstracting the query logic using something like the specification pattern, the implementation details whether they are in the form of a repository or directly executed on the DbContext are obfuscated and can remain separate. Here is an article that suggests a take on using the Specification Pattern to implement query objects: https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/specification-design-pattern-c814649be0ef

As such, I think if you are implementing query objects in this fashion and maintaing some fairly rigorous separation, you can implement them in the domain layer. Now, the "logic" of retrieval can be implemented on your domain entities.